# Set interval for the christocracy cordova-plugin-background plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to set interval to cordova geo location background plugin to send update in every 5 or 10 min to server .
I read the whole documentation and had no success . Anybody knows how to set the interval for this plugin

https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/blob/37f2cd9f6be82ca8ea3046c246b1866d4a669f06/README.md

Answer (score 1):

Ashish

### First analyze

After reading the documentation and browsing the sources, I think that kind of behaviour you want is not implemented by the plugin. Here you have the following parameters (see example):

- desiredAccuracy: 10
- stationaryRadius: 20
- distanceFilter: 30

For example for iOS (must be the same for Android, see sources and Android doc), with those parameters, you will get navigation events once the conditions are met, that is to say in this example when the distance from the previous event is more than 30 (meters).

See Apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/distanceFilter):

> distanceFilter
>
> The minimum distance (measured in meters) a device must move
>   horizontally before an update event is generated.

So if you need to get events at a regular interval, it's not good.

### Looking for a solution

I checked on SO the question and find some results: it seems possible, in iOS (did not checked for Android), to get regular updates based on a timeout. See this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410548/3136339 .
It is using a method called allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled ([doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout:)):

> allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout:
>
> Asks the location manager to defer the delivery of location updates
>   until the specified criteria are met.
>
> timeout
>
> ```
> The amount of time (in seconds) from the current time that must pass before event delivery resumes.
> ```

### To sum up

I think it is possible (for iOS at least), but you have to go deeper in the plugin you find to implement this use case by adding a parameter for example. If you do this work, you should upgrade the plugin on github for other users ;-)

Comment: You have to change the plugin native calls to use this functionality. You may add a parameter for your use between the plugin interface and native code to enable / disable this function, like they pass distanceFilter for example